# Limitations for sending emails

Tags: civimail, sparkpost

We are running a mass mailing from CiviCRM using the Sparkpost Extension. The cron job will only send 400 emails per execution.  Is this a limitation of CiviCRM? How do we increase it?

Environment:
WordPress 4.6.1 running Canvas-child theme.
CiviCRM 4.7.13

Answer (score 1):

At **Administer** > **CiviMail** > **Mailer Settings** (`civicrm/admin/mail`) you will find settings for CiviMail delivery.

Do your settings have a **Mailer Batch Limit** of 400? If so, this was probably set on your site at some point.

The default is 0 (unlimited) I think; if it was set to 400 on your site this may indicate the task was timing out before completion. If you're having that issue, running the mail task more frequently may be a good alternative to adjusting the batch limit.

[image: CiviMail Mailer Settings]

Comment: No we don't have a Batch Limit.It is set to 0, the default setting.